# Does Gluon Mobile support cross compilation?

Tags: javafx, gluon

I know Gluon uses GraalVM Native Image features to create native executable packages. But... What I need to know is:

- Can it can deploy native packages (executable) for Apple OS based devices (macOS and iOS) in Linux? Or Is it OS specific dependent like jpackage?

What about deploying Windows ".exe" packages in Linux, Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/#_requirements) for the Client plugin, there are some requisites to be met in order to create a native image.

So far, the following hosts are required for the possible native image targets:

- Linux: targets Linux (x86_64 desktop) and Android (aarch64). Embedded support is still experimental.
- Windows: targets Windows (x86_64 desktop). Optionally WSL 2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) can be used to target Linux/Android.
- MacOS X 10: targets Mac (x86_64 desktop) and iOS (arm64).

For each host you need a specific GraalVM build.

See the different [samples](https://gluonhq.com/developers/samples/), and the tutorials (like [this](https://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/notes/) one) to know more about each scenario.

Comment: Btw, Do I really need to set $JAVA_HOME as the same location to GraalVM? I use BellSoft JDK (It's bundled with JavaFX - make things easier for me...)

Comment: Getting: GraalVM installation directory not found. Either set GRAALVM_HOME as an environment variable or set graalvmHome in the client-plugin configuration

Comment: I already did everything instructed on docs, even used 'echo' keyword to verify the environment variables integrity...

Comment: Comments from an existing SO question is not the place for online/pair debugging. Please spend some time trying to fix the issue by reading the documentation, and try the command line instead of running from your IDE.